# How do construct a horizontally scrollable calendar in my appbar with Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, calendar, appbar

[image][image: this is how it is looking right now]

this is how it is looking right now for me.

[image: expected design of the calendar]

I haven't been able to find any plugins or any way to build this specific type of widget. I have been having trouble with this so your help will be immensely appreciated.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:healthonify_mobile/constants/text_styles.dart';
import 'package:healthonify_mobile/widgets/cards/add_workout.dart';
import 'package:healthonify_mobile/widgets/cards/average_calories_burnt.dart';
import 'package:healthonify_mobile/widgets/cards/reminder_card.dart';
import 'package:healthonify_mobile/widgets/cards/steps_card.dart';
import 'package:healthonify_mobile/widgets/cards/track_workout.dart';
import 'package:healthonify_mobile/widgets/cards/workout_details.dart';
import 'package:healthonify_mobile/widgets/other/calendar_appbar.dart';

class WorkoutScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: CalendarAppBar(),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              SizedBox(height: 12),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  WorkoutDetailsCard(),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 22),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  StepsCard(),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 22),
              Row(
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16),
                    child: Text(
                      'Track your workout',
                      style: openSans22DarkBold,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 12),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  TrackWorkoutCard(),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 22),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  AddWorkoutCard(),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 22),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  AverageCalBurntCard(),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 22),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  ReminderCard(),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 34),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CalendarAppBar extends StatefulWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  const CalendarAppBar({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => const Size.fromHeight(148.0);

  @override
  State<CalendarAppBar> createState() => _CalendarAppBarState();
}

class _CalendarAppBarState extends State<CalendarAppBar> {
  int selectedIndex = 0;
  DateTime now = DateTime.now();
  late DateTime lastDayOfMonth;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    lastDayOfMonth = DateTime(now.year, now.month + 1, 0);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      toolbarHeight: 148.0,
      title: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            children: const [
              Icon(
                Icons.arrow_back_ios,
                color: Colors.orange,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Text(
                  "Workout",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 16.0),
          SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
            child: Row(
              children: List.generate(
                lastDayOfMonth.day,
                (index) {
                  final currentDate =
                      lastDayOfMonth.add(Duration(days: index + 1));
                  final dayName = DateFormat('E').format(currentDate);
                  return Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                        left: index == 0 ? 16.0 : 0.0, right: 16.0),
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () => setState(
                        () {
                          selectedIndex = index;
                        },
                      ),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            height: 42.0,
                            width: 42.0,
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: selectedIndex == index
                                  ? Colors.orange
                                  : Colors.transparent,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(44.0),
                            ),
                            child: Text(
                              dayName.substring(0, 1),
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 24.0,
                                color: selectedIndex == index
                                    ? Colors.white
                                    : Colors.black54,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                          Text(
                            "${index + 1}",
                            style: const TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 16.0,
                              color: Colors.black54,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                          Container(
                            height: 2.0,
                            width: 28.0,
                            color: selectedIndex == index
                                ? Colors.orange
                                : Colors.transparent,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is some of the code that is using the appbar and there is not more than this linking elsewhere in the app so basically it is just 2 screens. i dont understand why the appbar is aligning the the left automatically even though i have no padding or offset.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try below code you get exact output based on your description

add package in `pubspec.yaml` file

```
intl: ^0.17.0
```

**Output:-**

[image]

**Code:-**

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DatePickerCustom extends StatefulWidget {
  const DatePickerCustom({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<DatePickerCustom> createState() => _DatePickerCustomState();
}

class _DatePickerCustomState extends State<DatePickerCustom> {
  int selectedIndex = 0;
  DateTime now = DateTime.now();
  late DateTime lastDayOfMonth;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    lastDayOfMonth = DateTime(now.year, now.month + 1, 0);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        toolbarHeight: 148.0,
        title: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              children: const [
                Icon(
                  Icons.arrow_back_ios,
                  color: Colors.orange,
                ),
                Expanded(
                    child: Text("Workout",
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,
                        )))
              ],
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 16.0),
            SingleChildScrollView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
              child: Row(
                children: List.generate(
                  lastDayOfMonth.day,
                  (index) {
                    final currentDate =
                        lastDayOfMonth.add(Duration(days: index + 1));
                    final dayName = DateFormat('E').format(currentDate);
                    return Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                          left: index == 0 ? 16.0 : 0.0, right: 16.0),
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () => setState(() {
                          selectedIndex = index;
                        }),
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              height: 42.0,
                              width: 42.0,
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: selectedIndex == index
                                    ? Colors.orange
                                    : Colors.transparent,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(44.0),
                              ),
                              child: Text(
                                dayName.substring(0, 1),
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 24.0,
                                  color: selectedIndex == index
                                      ? Colors.white
                                      : Colors.black54,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                            Text(
                              "${index + 1}",
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 16.0,
                                color: Colors.black54,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              ),
                            ),
                            const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                            Container(
                              height: 2.0,
                              width: 28.0,
                              color: selectedIndex == index
                                  ? Colors.orange
                                  : Colors.transparent,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: check i just updated answer

Comment: im getting an offset padding to the left and the widget is aligned to the right. how do i fix it?

Comment: i don't Understand please clear things so i resolved issue

Comment: the whole row including the back icon and the bottom row of the calendar has been shifted and aligned to the right ... in my case i dont know how thats happening. where can i share the screenshot so i can show you?

Comment: edit your answer and upload the screenshot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243481/discussion-between-syed-a-r-and-mohammedali).

Answer (score 1):

You just use the Listview.builder widget with the parameter `scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,`